# Прилипающая шапка

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Лендинг. Как сделать прилипающую шапку после скроллинга вниз на следующую страницу? И она должна подсвечивать ту ссылку, на которой странице мы находимся.

Comment: @skies, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/yt8k7dhk/ - вот еще пример

Answer (score 1):

1. Для подсвета ссылок нужно выделить css-класс, который будет как-то выделять её,

   `<\a class = "selected">Текущее положение<\/a>`
2. Для  определения, на какой мы странице, можно просто по логике вывести тупую до ужаса конструкцию PHP:

//  К примеру, для определенной страницы мы определенным образом подставляем значение переменной $var . Тогда выходит как-то так

```
\<a <?php if ($var == 'value'){ echo 'class = "selected" '; } ?> href = ""> Страница</a>
```

По поводу шапки, современные браузеры поддерживают такую интересную штуку в CSS, как `position:sticky`.

Как пример:

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 15px;
}
```

Но тут всё-таки могут выйти траблы с поддержкой, ибо черт его знает, какой у конечного юзера браузер, так что лучше использовать какие-нибудь библиотеки, как **jQuery Sticky-Kit** и тому подобные.

Comment: @Виталий RS, современные браузеры, в большей степени, [**не** поддерживают][1] "*position:sticky*". 

   [1]:http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: @Deonis значит, мне пора обновить браузер) 
Да и сам этой штукой никогда не пользовался, в принципе, так что мог и упустить из виду.

Answer (score 1):

Для одностраничной навигации можно использовать [этот плагин](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav).

А для фиксирования при скролле можно вот так:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $block = $('#block');

    if($(window).scrollTop() > $block.offset().top) {
        $block.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $block.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

Разумеется, в CSS нужно написать стили для класса fixed, чтобы зафиксировать нужный вам блок.